# Can IR Sensor TCRT1000 and TCRT5000 operate at 12V?

Tags: voltage, sensor, infrared

I asked chat GPT, and it said [TCRT1000](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83752/tcrt1000.pdf) and [TCRT5000](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83760/tcrt5000.pdf) are not suited for ops above 5V. But interestingly I have read a research paper where TCRT1000 has been used at 9V. I would like help decoding these datasheets and understanding whether its safe to use these sensors at 12V, I don't really trust Chatgpt, its lies ten times in a line.

Comment: Please don't use GPT and then ask here if it is right or wrong.

Comment: Your time might be better spent with the data sheets instead of an AI

Comment: GPT just spits out--very confidently regardless of truth--whatever words it predicts are likely to come next, given the previous words and its training data (a corpus of text taken--with dubious legality--from various sources). Many, many ICs are designed to work at 5 V and no more, so its training data will have had many instances of "[some sequence of letters and numbers] is not suitable for use above 5 V"--so when you ask it about some sequence of letters and numbers and its voltage capability, it deems it likely to be "not suitable for use above 5 V". Even though that's wrong.

Comment: GPT algorithms have no knowledge of truth or falsehood. They don't even know what truth *is*. They adopt the confident tone of someone who *does* know what truth is, because that's the predominant tone that people speak in when answering questions, but they will very confidently tell you complete fictions, sometimes even adding citations to papers that don't exist.

Comment: @Hearth yeah, I've actually experienced that. on being asked to find research papers, it found me several, complete with titles and author names, and they were just untraceable on the internet, their links (provided by gpt) also lead to nowhere. Don't really know what's the fuss about it, it even does math wrong many times. At least a computer should be able to compute right.

Comment: @DribbleNibble It can't do math because it doesn't know what math *is*. It is nothing more than predictive text--an advanced version of the same algorithm your phone uses to suggest the next word you're going to type.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because lack or research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they can be operated at 12V.

The data sheets say the other one is rated for 32V and the other for 70V.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll test it an let know. But what's wrong with my approach? One seeks opinions from any recourse. This is what AI and forums are both for.

Comment: @DribbleNibble as you yourself observed, chatgpt is unreliable. Whatever claims it spits out are essentially just noise, and don't add anything to the question itself. If you can't even trust it, why even make people check its work when you could ask those people that question directly? Learning and developing your skills can be done from reliable, human-checked sources (e.g. textbooks, application notes, this site, other forums, etc)

Comment: At what voltage the devices can be operated is not an opinion given by an algorithm or anyone. It is a fact that reads in the data sheet. If you don't trust GPT then don't use it.

Comment: @DribbleNibble Learning how to figure out things does not limit to electronics so everyone needs to learn some skills how to find what you need. I closed the data sheets already so I don't have page numbers. But you can do a text search in the PDF for strings "32" and "70" to find them yourself.

Comment: @Justme got it. Thanks :)